# Удаление шаблонных данных из строки php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть переменная, содержащая HTML вёрстку. Из нее нужно удалить все блоки вида

```
<blockquote><p><img src="/files/answer/6926092/acddd8f931ffa5f4931c492dc8a81483.png"></p></blockquote>
```

Попытался сделать так:

```
function DelImg ($text){
    $text = preg_replace('/<img.*>/Uis', '', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Соответственно этот обработчик оставляет

```
<blockquote><p></p></blockquote>
```

Пытался сделать как то так:

```
function DelImg ($text){
    $text = preg_replace('/<blockquote><p><img.*></p></blockquote>/Uis', '', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Так само собой ошибка.

Подскажите "шаблон" для preg_replace() Который бы сделал это за 1 "прогон", потому что в `<blockquote><p></p></blockquote>` хранится еще и текст, который нужно оставить. То есть удалить нужно только квоты, который содержат `img`

Comment: Друзья, за что влепили минус то?) Но спасибо за ответы! Проблема решена!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот пример работает, очень еффективно

```
function DelImg ($text)
{
    $text = preg_replace('/<blockquote><p><img.*?<\/blockquote>/', '', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Да, проверил! огромное спасибо!

Comment: Неправильный шаблон! Нужно `.*?` (нежадный делать)

Comment: все работает... thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите "шаблон" для preg_replace() Который бы сделал это за 1 "прогон"

Пробуйте такой регэксп: `/<blockquote><p><img[^>]+><\/p><\/blockquote>/`

Answer (score -1):

```html
function DelImg ($text){
    $text = preg_replace('/<blockquote>.*<img[^>]{0,}>.*<\/blockquote>/', '', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Так не работает(

Comment: Нерабочий регэксп!